# Api-Gateway Spring boot Variable URI

Tags: spring, spring-boot, api-gateway

I'm starting learning spring boot last month in an internship, so I have some problems. I'm working on api-gateway of spring boot. I want to configure an URI that is programmable. I'll give you an example:

```
@Bean
public RouteLocator myRoutes (RouteLocatorBuilder builder){
return builder.routes()
            .route(r -> r.path("/test/{appID}")

                    .uri("http://aa.aa.com/aaaa/app/{appID}")

            )
```

I want to go the every URI with {appID}.

Can you please help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below code for routelocator

```
@Bean
    public RouteLocator customRouteLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes()
          .route("r1", r -> r.host("**.yourdomainname.com")
            .and()
            .path("/abc")
            .uri("http://yourdomainname.com"))
          .route(r -> r.host("**.yourdomainname.com")
            .and()
            .path("/myOtherRouting")
            .filters(f -> f.prefixPath("/myPrefix"))
            .uri("http://othersite.com")
            .id("myOtherID"))
        .build();
    }
```

Hope it will solve your issue.
if you have more doubt please refer [here](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway)

Comment: I want to redirect from http://localhost:8080/projects to http://*.*.com:8080/mos-resources-rs/1.0/projects, I wrote this code, it doesn't work unfortunately... That was my code  .route("Get/Put/Post project", r -> r.host("api.***.com")
                        .and()
                        .path("/projects")
                        .filters(f -> f.setPath("/mos-resources-rs/1.0/projects"))
                        .uri(OutputHost))

                .build();